# Update all documents in a subcollection of another subcollection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing the client-side logic for letting a user update their avatar (aka, photoURL). What I need to do is update every document in a  subcollection called `comments` which exists under a collection called `posts` for that user and update the photoURL property.

Here is an example path to the user's comments subcollection I need to access:

`/users/XrMD3azk4Jess5KNTSICv4RYEj02/posts/what-architecture-style-is-this_r3nosJHQIt/comments`

[image]

How would I loop through each posts document and update each comment doc ?

As a newbie to FireStore, how do I reference the subcollection of a collection and then loop over it and update each comment document?

If someone can give me a hand so I can get started on the right path that would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    const commentsCol = this.$fire.firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc(`${this.userProfile.uid}`)
      .collection('posts')
      // I need to loop through here and get all the post docs, right?
      // ... then get the comments collection
      .collection('comments')
    const querySnapshot = await commentsCol.get()
    querySnapshot.forEach((comment) => update the photoURL property here..)
```

Comment: This should be a fairly straightforward three-step process: 1) [read all documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) from the subcollection, 2) loop over the results, 3) [update each document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data). Did you try anything yet?

Comment: So I have `const postsCol = this.$fire.firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(`${this.userProfile.uid}`)
          .collection('posts')` but can't figure out how to get to comments subcollection

Comment: That should be `.collection("comments")`. But if you've tried something already, editing your question to include drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen OK Frank, I'm struggling here...just a simple problem but I may be way overthinking this? See my updated code above...I give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now that your comments are on a third level, which makes this more tricky than usual.

You have two main options:

1. You can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to get all `comments` across the entire database (so for all users). This is probably not what you want to do.
2. You can load the comments for each post of one user, by first loading all posts for that user, looping over those, and then loading all comments for each post.

With the second approach you are wasting the reading of the posts for the user, but it's probably a lot better than the additional comments from other users that you'd end up loading in the first approach.

The ideal situation here would be if you could load all comments from all posts of a specific user with a single query, but the Firestore API unfortunately doesn't allow that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! Since this is just concept based at the moment, would it just be better for me to put the comments in a root collection instead of subcollections ? Then I could query the comments collection for the user's uid and then update the photoURL there.

Comment: There is no singular "better" here (or in most NoSQL data modeling), it all depends on your use-cases. But if you're considering that, you can also add the same fields to each comment in its current location, and possibly use a collection group query with conditions to select the comments on posts for the user.

Comment: Hey @redshift Anything else needed here?

Comment: sorry, let me get back to you soon.